# What is "amp't" in "Am I or amp't I?"

Tags: meaning

In Terry Pratchett's Equal Rites, Esk, the main character, asks: "Am I or amp't I?"

What does "amp't" stand for here?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a tympo? ;)

Comment: @Kris: I think only the author can be sure in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The logical form is "[Amn't I?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractions_of_negated_auxiliary_verbs_in_English#Amn.27t)", mirroring "Aren't you?" and "Isn't she?".

I find it difficult to sound the *n* in *amn't* and instead produce  a bilabial plosive. Perhaps Pratchett and Esk do too.

Comment: +1 purely for the head-scratching you've just caused me by conflating author Pratchett's idiolect with that of his own fictional creation Esk!

Answer (score 4):

"Aren't I" - it's intended as a joke accent or childish mistake.

Since you would expect *am* to have an opposite *am not* or shortened to *am't*

Comment: Why "amp't" and not "amn't", I wonder.

Comment: Perhaps Pratchett had a specific person or regional accent in mind. I think there are English Midlands dialects that might say "amp't".

Comment: @slim,Urbycoz: In my SE UK dialect, I couldn't easily hear, let alone articulate, a difference between *amp't* and *amn't* in casual speech. And speaking for myself, I think the latter form seems a more "natural" way of writing the sound I'd actually be making, since I'm accustomed to ignoring or downplaying the audible significance of the letter "p" in such contexts.

Comment: Actually, the historical contraction of _am not_ is _ain't_. Kind of obvious, in fact. It generalized early to all pronouns and was stigmatized for it by Lowthians, so that now it's become stigmatized as well in its original first person singular, too. A cheeky contraction that didn't know its place is now relegated to the gutter, where it belongs. Meanwhile every new generation discovers the joys of _ain't,_ but dare not speak its name. Sounds like Downtown Abby.

Answer (score 1):

Sixty years ago, my family moved from Wales to the Hebrides. My memory is that there all the children and a few adults used the tag question "Amn't I?" when I would use "Aren't I": e.g. "I'm right, amn't I?" And up there they did not insert the "p" sound - it was easy to say and closer to "ammunt" with the emphasis strongly on "am". (Even as a child, I thought it was grammatically more sensible than the form I used.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a phonological process called *excrescence*. For example, say "Noam Chomsky", and you'll notice that it sounds like there's a [p] in the last name. Pratchett is just inventing how *am't* would be pronounced, if people said that instead of *aren't*.

Comment: Which led to a chimpanzee in the psych lab being named "Nim Chimpsky".